# Cannot add Firebase cloud messaging Post launch

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to integrate Firebase Cloud Messaging after launching your app on play store.
It went live on play store in early march and for the past 1 month I've been trying to add FCM to it. It was not working in testing. I am using flutter for developing my app.

I read a comment on stackoverflow that I cannot add it post launch.
Can someone give me a confirmation on this.

Comment: Good day...  There's no problem adding fcm or any new feature post launch of your app.. Just add the fcm functionality on your app's next version and just publish a new release on play store.

Comment: You can add it but it requires and update

Comment: So if i don't post an update on play store will it not work.
I've completed the code. I'm running it in testing on my device but it is not working.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Are you asking how to run code on a device that doesn't have the code already on it?